# how to call MKTileOverlay "url" function from subclass? getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, mapkit, mktileoverlay

I am getting a runtime error at the point marked below? How to call MKTileOverlay "url" function from subclass? getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION?

Basically want to show custom tiles in some places, but when not available drop back to standard Apple map tiles.

```
class GCMapOverlay : MKTileOverlay {
    override func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL {
        // Get local custom map tile if available
        let optionalUrl = Bundle.main.url(
            forResource: "\(path.y)",
            withExtension: "png",
            subdirectory: "tiles/\(path.z)/\(path.x)",
            localization: nil)
        NSLog("tiles/\(path.z)/\(path.x)/\(path.y)")

        guard let url = optionalUrl else {
            // Local tile not available - want to drop back to an apple maps tile (as if MKTileOverlay wasn't subclassed)
            return super.url(forTilePath: path)    // <== RUNTIME ERROR: NetworkLoad (10): EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
        }

        // Local tile available so return
        return url
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
func setupTileRenderer() {
    let overlay = GCMapOverlay()
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
    mapView.addOverlay(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
    tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)
}
```

Comment: oh, missed it - will look when back home thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true` and change your guard statement so it loads a clear 256x256 tile.

```
guard let url = optionalUrl else {
    return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "emptyTile", withExtension: "png")!
}
```

Since all of your custom tiles are already stored locally they will be immediately loaded over the default Apple tiles which makes `canReplaceMapContent` unnecessary.

Make sure your custom tiles don't have alpha in them otherwise the Apple tile will be visible below.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `MKTileOverlay` but the documentation for `url(forTilePath:)` states:

> The default implementation of this method uses the template string you provided at initialization time to build a URL to the specified tile image.

And the `MKTileOverlay` class provides the initializer:

```
init(urlTemplate:)
```

But when you create an instance of `GCMapOverlay`, you don't use that initializer.

Replacing:

```
let overlay = GCMapOverlay()
```

with:

```
let overlay = GCMapOverlay(urlTemplate: someAppropriateTemplate)
```

or overriding the `urlTemplate` property in your subclass should resolve your issue when calling `super.url(forTilePath:)`.

Comment: thanks - the issue is I am not sure what the "default" urlTemplate actually is for standard operation of maps, and how to get this?  For example I do now how to fall back to OpenMaps, as I know how to specify the URL template, however I don't know the equivalent for IOS maps.   Or even if this approach (within the GCMapOveral class) can actually be used to solve my requirement?